# Not able to detect toast message on android app

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, android-toast

I am using Appium for android app & i have to deal with Toast message. I am able to see toast message text but Uiautomator is not able to detect toast element. So it there any method available in Appium to deal with toast message.[image: toast message]

Comment: can you please share screenshot of properties of that toast as per UIautomator? Also share your webdriver code that how you are finding that toast?

Comment: Uiautomator is not able to detect Toast message & i am trying following code "driver.findElement(By.linkText("Please enable Network or GPS"))"

Answer (score 1):

`Toast` is designed to be fire and forget, there's no way to retrieve its status once `show()` is called.

Comment: Is there any method to detect this toast message through appium because i have search about this & could not find any solution. Solution is available with Selendroid.